# Unity 5 collider is not working

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I have 2 prefabs (a character and a wall), I attached a capsule to the player and a cube to the wall. Both capsule and player, have the collider component. The problem is that my character walks through the wall. I need your help, please!

Answer (score 2):

`Collider` defined without `RigidBody` component is called **Static Collider** in Unity. If you do so, Unity assumes that the object will never move in the scene.

On the other hand, if your object is an active one (moving), you need to attach `RigidBody` component in addition to `Collider` component.

In your case, you need to attach a rigidbody to your character.

For more info: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RigidBody` component to them.